# Use URL as variable in php

Tags: php, url

I needed to use my URL as my variable for example test.com/user/mark
I use this code

```
$test=explode( '/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
echo $test[2];
```

It is working properly but when I tried to access it folders are not working properly CSS and JS folder is not working, what could be the proper solution for this ?

Comment: What you mean by use my url? What exactly you looking for? Can you provide an output you are expecting from above code?

Comment: Try `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$test[2];`

Comment: Use the variable as id for example www.facebook.com/martney , Ill be using Martney as my Variable $username=explode( '/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ); then still accessing facebook.com but not different page.

Comment: http://localhost/biyahero/test.php/mark , Accessing test.php but using mark as my ID